# handled 'Uncaught Exception' still crashing the app

Tags: android, exception

I am handling the Uncaught Exception in android as follow

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
        handleUncaughtException(thread, e);
    }
})

public void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
    Helper.logUncaughtExceptionToFile(e); // Just to log the exception
}
```

It works fine for me, it handle the exceptions, but when exception happened my function got called then the application crashes. Is this how it should work? I don't want the application to crash

Comment: please post your logcat crashes.

Comment: there is no exceptions in my logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the thread related exceptions are being handled.if the particular thread has the job of fetching data to UI then the application crashes without the required values for generating UI.

Comment: it would be helpful if you hit the up button.